# Run gradle task with Spring Profiles (Integration tests)

Tags: java, spring, gradle, profiling, spring-profiles

Need to run tests via gradle with spring profiles.

```
gradle clean build
```

I've added task:

```
task beforeTest() {
    doLast {
      System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "DEV")
    }
}

test.dependsOn beforeTest
```

And my test definition is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("TestProfile")
public class SomeTest {
```

But this construction doesn't work for me.

Gradle runs tests.

Answer (score 25):

I think you are wanting to set a system property in the runtime/test JVM but you are incorrectly setting a system property in the build-time JVM (ie the Gradle daemon).

See [Test.systemProperty(String, Object)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#systemProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Eg:

```
test {
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'DEV'
}
```

... and another note on your attempt. Please note that tasks have a `doFirst` and a `doLast` method so you wouldn't need a separate task for what you were attempting.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me

Comment: Just a note this property needs to be added in the build.gradle file

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
test {
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'ci'
}
```

Now when I do `gradlew test` it runs with the `ci` profile.

Comment: You shouldn't do this in a `doFirst {...}`it's task config which should be done in the configuration phase, not the execution phase. See [build phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases)

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "DEV")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Wonder if this is a very late reply? But I have encountered the similar problem with situation.

1. Using @Profiles in springboot src/test/* folder.
2. The @ActiveProfiles is actually activated (when viewing logs), but it doesn't use the @Profile when executed with gradle test. However, the @Profile was working in Eclipse Editor when JUnit test was executed.

So in the end i found that @Profile needs to be in **src/main/*** folder. Gradle test seems to have precedence over /src/main rather than /src/test. With this my @Profile("test") was converted into @Profile("!test"). There was no added spring.profiles.active into the gradle built.

[Negating profile](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)