# Best way to decouple integration test cases from build (gradle spring-boot)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

I am working on a large project and need to offer users the ability to optionally enable or disable local integration test cases ( For pipeline, test cases must be enforced).

Comment: Could you tell us more about the project? (ex. pipeline, testcase library etc..)

Comment: There is a concept of [Profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) in Spring.
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256956/run-gradle-task-with-spring-profiles-integration-tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, welcome to the community.

Next, you can modify the `test` task inside the `build.gradle` file or maybe add a new task called `integrationTest` and implement your custom logic there.

As an instance, you can check this gist on Github: [Separating tests from integration tests with Gradle](https://gist.github.com/eriwen/5245908)

You can also use `@Profile` annotation to your integration test classes and run your tests with different profiles. You can read more about profiles using the following link: [Spring Profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Reza. This gives me much to look into. Cheers

Comment: You can also find some plugins equivalent to Maven `Surefire` and `Failsafe` plugins. But, the Github Gist that I shared in my answer works perfectly, at least for me.

Comment: The gist linked to above worked perfectly for me too and didn't require adding @Profile annotations to all my tests.

Comment: Where does the test function come from? I tried to import it but it didn't work.